# Accessing javascript data in a function

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have this function:

```
function formSubmitted(json, grandTotal) {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../quotes/create",
            data: {
                quote: {
                  name: json.name,
                  json: JSON.stringify(json),
                  email: json.email,
                  uid: json.id,
                  grand_total: grandTotal,
                  postcode: json.postcode,
                }
            },
             dataType:'text',
             success: function(data,status,xhr){
                console.log(status);
                alert("AWESOME!");

                window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/thanks?id=json.id")
             },
             error: function(xhr,status,error){
               console.log(status,error);
               alert("ERROR!");
             }

        });
}
```

It all works fine but what I want to do is redirect with window.location in the success: to

```
http://www.example.com/thanks?id=json.id
```

with json.id being the same as

```
uid: json.id,
```

In the code above. What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Perfect. Want to make it an answer and ill accept?

Comment: Better just close your question :) This is a simple typographical error and it doesn't really belong on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function formSubmitted(json, grandTotal) {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../quotes/create",
            data: {
                quote: {
                  name: json.name,
                  json: JSON.stringify(json),
                  email: json.email,
                  uid: json.id,
                  grand_total: grandTotal,
                  postcode: json.postcode,
                }
            },
             dataType:'text',
             success: function(data,status,xhr){
                console.log(status);
                alert("AWESOME!");

                window.location.assign("http://www.example.com/thanks?id=" + json.id)
             },
             error: function(xhr,status,error){
               console.log(status,error);
               alert("ERROR!");
             }

        });
}
```